# Fetch coordinates close to each other

Tags: php, coordinates

I have about 15000 coordinates. I want to calculate which of these are a 100 meters or less from each other. For now, I'm using the code down below for calculating the distance. It takes quite a while when I have this many coordinates though.

Is there any way to boost performance? Maybe by filtering out coordinates that are several of hundred meters away and then more accurately calculate the distance with the function below.

```
  $earthRadius = 6371000;

  // convert from degrees to radians
  $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
  $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
  $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
  $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

  $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;
  $a = pow(cos($latTo) * sin($lonDelta), 2) + pow(cos($latFrom) * sin($latTo) - sin($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta), 2);
  $b = sin($latFrom) * sin($latTo) + cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * cos($lonDelta);

  $angle = atan2(sqrt($a), $b);

  return $angle * $earthRadius;
```

Comment: if you need to compare all of them in pairs, you'll need to put that code in a double loop for the most naive implementation I can figure out

Comment: As you find each pair you could store each matching pair in an array. Check the array for those pairs as you loop, before you calculate the distance for that pair again. If it is in the array you can skip the calculation for that pair.

Comment: This generated a healthy discussion in the office this morning (*you could say we're in the business of coordinate reference systems*). Suffice it to say that there are many ways to conquer the problem, each with varying levels of efficiency and all with  levels of complexity ranging from mildly difficult(the method I mention above) to mind-numbingly difficult but with extreme efficiency. Could PHP handle something as complex as that given what it is designed to do vs. other, more mathematically capable languages? Maybe. If you'd like I can answer with pseudo-code for the idea proposed above.

Comment: I've tried what you describe but there is still a lot of calculating going on. As I said in the question - is there a fast way to calculate the rough distance maybe? Some of the coordinates are miles apart from each other and I would save tons of calculating if I could filter them out.

Comment: Regardless of the distance apart you're going to have to calculate *something* to determine if the measurement should be left out. You could possible 'order' the array by the x's and y's and that would help to a small degree but may be more unmanageable than helpful.